# Good literature about cross validation

Tags: references, cross-validation

Does anybody know a good book/webpage to start learning the techniques of cross validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/) has great information.

In particular, the fourth section of [this PDF](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/lectures/03-evaluation/lecture-03.pdf) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 7):

If cross-validation is to be used for model/feature selection, it is worth bearing in mind that it is possible to over-fit the cross-validation statistic and end up with a model that performs poorly, and the optimised cross-validation statistic can be a severly optimistic performance estimate.  The effects of this can be surprisingly large.  See [Ambroise and McLachlan](http://www.pnas.org/content/99/10/6562.abstract) for an example of this in a feature selection setting and [Cawley and Talbot](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v11/cawley10a.html) for an example in a model selection setting.

Comment: It is good to mention it, but it should be double said that those are examples of misusing or overtrusting CV, not some drawbacks of the method itself.

Comment: indeed, however it is a way in which it is quite commonly misused - so it is important to be aware of when learning about cross-validation!  More cross-validation is often a good solution, i.e. nested cross-validation, or as Stone puts it "double-cross" validation.  The problem affects pretty much any feature or model selection criterion that is optimised to get a model; there is nothing special about cross-validation in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend [*Cross-Validation* by Payam Refaeilzadeh, Lei Tang, and Huan Liu.](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_565)